# the_widget for theme widgets

Tags: wordpress, widget, themes

I created several widgets with own theme
one of them should display group of other widgets from some widget area
I get array with widget IDs
and get instances of them
but function "the_widget" don't display it

code that I use

```
foreach ($instance["widgets"] as $widgetID) {
$wdgtvar = 'widget_'._get_widget_id_base( $widgetID );
$idvar = _get_widget_id_base( $widgetID ); $instance = get_option( $wdgtvar );
$idbs = str_replace( $idvar.'-', '', $widgetID );

the_widget($idvar,$instance[$idbs]);

}
```

can you help me with that?